# Get post from facebook for Android app

Tags: android, facebook, api

I need some help, I'm developing an Android app that should get the home page's posts of a Facebook user and it might display them. I search in Facebook API documentation but I didn't find any answer, so how can I get the posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different endpoints for this, all of them are in the API docs - including example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed

You cannot get the whole newsfeed, only the posts on your own wall:

> The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by
>   this person, or by others on this person's profile.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to get only the home page post? Because I can't find it on documentation. I mean the posts that appears when you login not only the one you post or you were tagged

Comment: no, as you can read in the docs, you can only get your own posts or posts of your friend on your wall, but not posts of you friends in general - or posts of pages and stuff. i will add the relevant text to the answer.